# change installed user of application

Tags: inno-setup

let assume I have installer created with PrivilegesRequired=admin and DefaultDirName={%APPDATA} properties.If the current user does not have a admin prevelegies the application will be installed admins appdata directory. after some modifications in application iv'e changed PrivilegesRequired property to lowest. although the app id is the same in both cases, the new installer will install application in different directory. so the question is: Is there a way to kind of "transfer" application from admin to current users directory ?

Comment: What does the "transfer" mean? Do you actually want to transfer anything? Or do you just want to change the installation part, if the previous one is not accesssible anymore, due to lower privileges?

Comment: The issue is, that after second installer run, there is two different versions of app. I want to have only one , the second one

Comment: You need administrator privileges to uninstall the first. So you would have to get administrator privileges at least for this first upgrade (or at least for an uninstaller executed from unprivileged installer). For the further upgrades, you can do with lowest privileges --- Is this what you want?